# Looking for A Lightweight Web Proxy

Tags: proxy

I'm looking for a lightweight web proxy, it must:

1. Be free (as in beer)
2. Run on linux or bsd
3. Support user logins
4. Support clustering

What have you used or heard good things about?

Sorry I can't be more specific ...

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites because of their very limited lifespan and narrow scope. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your goals, I'd consider [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/). It's very fast, reliable and it has plenty of options. I use it in some projects and its performance is great.